# Azure DevOps build scheduled trigger for every hours is not working

Tags: azure-devops

I have defined a `.yml` file like below. I expect it to run every one hour on my branch 'kabhukya-cicd', but it is not working.

```
pool:
  name: Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019
  demands:
  - npm
  - azureps

# Scheduled triggers
schedules:
- cron: "0 */1 * * *"
  displayName: every one hour trigger
  branches:
    include:
    - kabhukya-cicd
  always: true

# npm install, npm start, npm link steps
steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    verbose: false

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm start'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    verbose: false
    customCommand: start

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm link'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    verbose: false
    customCommand: link
```

I have tried changing the cron schedules, but no luck..

Comment: this looks right (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#scheduled-triggers).  only thing I can think of: `Each cron schedule has a maximum of 100 pipeline runs per week. If you need more, you can split your cron schedule into multiple cron schedules that each result in 100 or less pipeline runs per week.`. Split your cron into 2 expressions, one to build `0 */2 * * *` and one to build `0 1-23/2 * * *`

Comment: **yes. it works.***

Answer (score 4):

Due to the way yaml works, only the yaml file in a branch will be considered for that branch, so if the branch filters should include a branch "kabhukya-cicd" but the yaml file in branch "kabhukya-cicd" does not contain that schedule with those branch filters, it will not be evaluated. It is a common complication that you could be hitting.

You can also refer to this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/613157/new-cron-schedule-not-working.html) for other solutions. In this case, there are different solutions provided by contributors who have the same issue with you.